# treeview item select jumps to top of page

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I select my asp.net tree-view check-box node it auto posts-back causing the webpage to jump to the top of the page.How can i prevent this from happening? I came across this but its in vb.net.[Vb.net equivalent](http://forums.asp.net/t/1187714.aspx/1).I am using c#.

**c# Code**

```
        void TreeViewAddItems_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
             ........
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your code is running at the server, so when the user clicks an expand button, it is making a server request and then re-rendering the page.  The re-rendering of the page causes the scroll to reset to the top.  I doubt you want to make a full page request every time the user expands a node.  You might be better off using client side script to request data from the server and dynamically put it into the tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try the VB.net approach in the post you mentioned, just use the `ScriptManager` in the same way:

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType, "selectNode", ("var elem = document.getElementById(\'" 
                + (tree.ClientID + "_SelectedNode\');var node = document.getElementById(elem.value);node.scrollIntoView(true);elem.scrollL" +
                "eft=0;")), true);
```